# Dojo popup date picker

Tags: dojo, datepicker

how do i make up the popup datepicker in dojo which should have seperate dropdown box for year,month..?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a date picker with separate year and month drop downs... I use dojo DateTextBox. The implementation is simple...

```
    require(‘dijit.form.DateTextBox’); 
   <input type=”text” dojoType=”dijit.form.DateTextBox” name=”date” id=”date”/>
```

And why would you want separate year and month selectors when its easier for the user to select date from a calendar??? You can take out any part of the date on server side as you please once it is posted....

Answer (score 0):

@Black Rider - it's better if you disable the ability for users to type in a date field.  This way, you don't have to worry about validation if they just can select a date from the date picker.

I've had applications where users would need to select a date from many years in the past, e.g. 2002 or even the late nineties.  What if you have an app where someone has to enter their birthday?

You could use a [jQuery date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year) instead, where you can easily add the year.

Answer (score 0):

What Black Rider said is true (and DateTextBox is a great widget), HOWEVER there are also "mobile" dojo widgets that have what you are looking for:

1) "ValuePickerDatePicker" - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ValuePickerDatePicker.html#dojox-mobile-valuepickerdatepicker

2) "SpinWheelDatePicker" (very iPhone-y) - h[ttp://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/SpinWheelDatePicker.html#dojox-mobile-spinwheeldatepicker](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/SpinWheelDatePicker.html#dojox-mobile-spinwheeldatepicker)